# Find the min and max from an unstructured array

Tags: r

I have the following vector and it shows the possible values that a variable can take. As you can see, it's not user-friendly and I'm having a hard time finding a systemic way of going through and identifying the min and max values. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
[211] "-1\n1-960"                                                         "-1\n1-960"                                                        
[213] "-1\n1-960"                                                         "-1\n1\n2\n3"                                                      
[215] "-1\n0\n1\n\n2\n3\n\n4\n\n5"                                        "-1\nF\nG\nH\nP\nR\nS\nU"                                          
[217] "-1\n0\n1\n2\n3"                                                    "-1\n0\n1"                                                         
[219] "-1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6"                                           "-1\n0-255"                                                        
[221] "-1\n0-255"                                                         "-1\n0-255"                                                        
[223] "-1\n0-255"                                                         "-1\n0-255"                                                        
[225] "-1\n0\n0.01–0.99\n1\n1.01–99.99"                                   "-1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n\n6\n\n7\n8\n\n9\n10\n11\n12"               
[227] "-1\n0\n1\n\n2\n\n3\n4\n5\n\n6"                                     "-1\n0\n1\n2\n\n3\n\n4\n5\n6"
```

The value "-1\n1-960" refers to the possible range of values being between 1 and 960. -1 doesn't mean anything and should be disregarded, along with all letters.

For example:

```
"-1\n1-960" 
"-1\n0\n1\n\n2\n\n3\n4\n5\n\n6"                                     "-1\n0\n1\n2\n\n3\n\n4\n5\n6"
```

Should result in:

```
max    min
960    1
6      0 
6      0
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a special parser for this. If you can't find one, perhaps you might want to process this outside of R or find a package that does this. Something like Boost.Karma from C++ would be appropriate for C++ but I'm not sure for R.

Comment: Please show some sample output so it is clear what you want to do.

Comment: Also show sample input, using `dput`.  What you show is very hard to enter interactively.

Comment: I'm guessing that -255 is some sort of missing value marker. Some of thos character values could be parsed in R as "numeric" values but others would throw an error if you tried to parse as such. What were you expecting from `1-960`. That's an expression, so neither numeric nor character.

Comment: Well your additional edit says "-1\n1-960" should all be removed and yet you are using it for values????

Comment: "(minus)1 doesn't mean anything."  reads a lot like "it doesn't mean anything" but isn't the same.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the leading -1, you can split on newlines.  Then, since a `-` means a range, you can also split on `-` characters, as the two numbers give the min and max of the range.  So here's some code:

```
 lapply(
        strsplit(
                 gsub('^-1\n', '', dat),
                 '\n|-'
        ), 
        function(x) range(x)
 )

[[1]]
[1] "1"   "960"

[[2]]
[1] "1"   "960"

[[3]]
[1] "1"   "960"

[[4]]
[1] "1" "3"

[[5]]
[1] ""  "5"

[[6]]
[1] "F" "U"

[[7]]
[1] "0" "3"

[[8]]
[1] "0" "1"

[[9]]
[1] "0" "6"

[[10]]
[1] "0"   "255"

[[11]]
[1] "0"   "255"

[[12]]
[1] "0"   "255"

[[13]]
[1] "0"   "255"

[[14]]
[1] "0"   "255"

[[15]]
[1] "0"          "1.01–99.99"

[[16]]
[1] ""  "9"

[[17]]
[1] ""  "6"

[[18]]
[1] ""  "6"
```

Comment: Why isn't the min of "-1\n1-960" minus one?

Comment: I'm basing that on his edit.  `"-1\n1-960"` results in 1, 960.  The only way to get a minimum of 1 out of that, is if `-` is a separator character and not a unary minus.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment with additional code which might or might not be a partial answer:

I'm guessing that -255 is some sort of missing value marker. Some of those character values (at the moment) could be parsed in R as "numeric" values, but others would throw an error if you tried to parse as such. What were you expecting from `1-960`. That's an expression, so neither numeric nor character.

```
dat <- c( "-1\n1-960"                 ,                                        "-1\n1-960",                                                        
 "-1\n1-960"                        ,                                 "-1\n1\n2\n3"          ,                                            
 "-1\n0\n1\n\n2\n3\n\n4\n\n5"        ,                                "-1\nF\nG\nH\nP\nR\nS\nU",                                          
 "-1\n0\n1\n2\n3"                     ,                               "-1\n0\n1"                ,                                         
 "-1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6"             ,                              "-1\n0-255"                ,                                        
 "-1\n0-255"                            ,                             "-1\n0-255"                 ,                                       
 "-1\n0-255"                             ,                            "-1\n0-255"                  ,                                      
 "-1\n0\n0.01–0.99\n1\n1.01–99.99"        ,                           "-1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n\n6\n\n7\n8\n\n9\n10\n11\n12" ,              
 "-1\n0\n1\n\n2\n\n3\n4\n5\n\n6"           ,                          "-1\n0\n1\n2\n\n3\n\n4\n5\n6" )

scandat <- sapply( dat, function(x) try( scan(textConnection(x)) ) )
# Lots of error messages but wrapping the scan call in try let's it continue
# So these are the items that could be parsed as numeric:

> scandat[ sapply(scandat,class)=="numeric" ]
$`-1\n1\n2\n3`
[1] -1  1  2  3

$`-1\n0\n1\n\n2\n3\n\n4\n\n5`
[1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5

$`-1\n0\n1\n2\n3`
[1] -1  0  1  2  3

$`-1\n0\n1`
[1] -1  0  1

$`-1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6`
[1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6

$`-1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n\n6\n\n7\n8\n\n9\n10\n11\n12`
 [1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

$`-1\n0\n1\n\n2\n\n3\n4\n5\n\n6`
[1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6

$`-1\n0\n1\n2\n\n3\n\n4\n5\n6`
[1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

I'm not cleaning this up but you could replace the funky names with womething else and it would print better:

```
> sapply( scandat[ sapply(scandat,class)=="numeric" ], function(x) list(minx=min(x), maxx=max(x) )
+ )
     -1\n1\n2\n3 -1\n0\n1\n\n2\n3\n\n4\n\n5 -1\n0\n1\n2\n3 -1\n0\n1 -1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6
minx -1          -1                         -1             -1       -1                     
maxx 3           5                          3              1        6                      
     -1\n0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n\n6\n\n7\n8\n\n9\n10\n11\n12 -1\n0\n1\n\n2\n\n3\n4\n5\n\n6 -1\n0\n1\n2\n\n3\n\n4\n5\n6
minx -1                                                 -1                            -1                         
maxx 12                                                 6                             6
```

Comment: According to OP's edit, "-1" should be removed, as well as any letter.

Comment: Actually all of "-1\n1-960" should be removed.

Comment: OP says that in "-1\n1-960", "-1" means nothing and should be removed, as well as "\" and "n". Only "1-960" should be kept.

Comment: Well, it says that 1-960 is a possible range. It doesn't say that they shopuld be considered values.